# Left alignment of a system of equations and extra vertical space between them

Tags: numbering, vertical-alignment

I am trying to obtain something like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align}
\phi_{\mathcal{C}\Phi} \colon \mathcal{C} &\longrightarrow \Phi \\
 \order & \longmapsto F(x,y)\\
\phi_{\Phi \mathcal{C}} \colon \Phi  &\longrightarrow \mathcal{C} \\
 F(x,y) & \longmapsto \order
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

but with an extra space between these two functions, and only two numberings like here

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % to work PDFLaTex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}} 
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
\phi_{\mathcal{C}\Phi} \colon \mathcal{C} &\longrightarrow \Phi\\
\order & \longmapsto F(x,y)
\end{aligned}
\\
\intertext{}
\begin{aligned}
\phi_{\Phi \mathcal{C}}\colon \Phi &\longrightarrow \mathcal{C}\\
   F(x,y) & \longmapsto \order
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

In this version I get the numbering exactly in a way I want +  the extra space but I am unable to fix the arrows alignment and  the functions alignment.

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `pdftex` option for `graphicx` and `hyperref` should not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` for getting equation numbers and `\\[2ex]` for the additional space

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}   %% no need of pdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}  %% no need of amsmath, already loaded by mathtools
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}   %% no need of pdftex
\DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}     %%<------------------------
\phi_{\mathcal{C}Φ} \colon \mathcal{C} &\longrightarrow Φ\\
 \order & \longmapsto F(x,y)
  \end{split}\\[2ex]         %%%<----------- here  adjust 2ex accordingly
  \begin{split}     %%<------------------------
\phi_{Φ\mathcal{C}} \colon Φ &\longrightarrow \mathcal{C} \\
 F(x,y) & \longmapsto \order
 \end{split}
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am after! Thank you!